# PySpark Leverage Function on MapType Column Values

Tags: pyspark, lambda, user-defined-functions

Below is a dataframe that represents what I'm trying to accomplish. Please note though, that the function I want to leverage is a bit more complex than this example.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

arrayData = [
        ('1',{1:100,2:200}),
        ('1',{1:100,2:None})]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data=arrayData, schema = ['id','value'])
```

What I'd like to do is to leverage withColumn to create a new column with a new map typeobject that a function has been applied to.

Let's say I wanted to square every value. I know I can create a udf that multiplies values by 2 and use withColumn... However that doesn't appear to work with applying to the MapType.

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
arrayData = [
        ('1',{1:200,2:200},{1:400,2:400}),
        ('1',{1:100,2:None},{1:200,2:None})]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data=arrayData, schema = ['id','value','newCol'])
```

Lastly, I need to maintain parallelism and am trying to avoid explode as I want to keep it in a single row. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work for you, but this UDF works perfectly fine with me

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def sq(m):
    return {k:e**2 if e is not None else None for k,e in m.items()}

print(sq({1:100,2:200}))  # {1: 10000, 2: 40000}
print(sq({1:100,2:None})) # {1: 10000, 2: None}

(df
    .withColumn('newCol', F.udf(sq, T.MapType(T.LongType(), T.LongType()))('value'))
    .show(10, False)
)

# Output
# +---+---------------------+------------------------+
# |id |value                |newCol                  |
# +---+---------------------+------------------------+
# |1  |{1 -> 100, 2 -> 200} |{1 -> 10000, 2 -> 40000}|
# |1  |{1 -> 100, 2 -> null}|{1 -> 10000, 2 -> null} |
# +---+---------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: My concern with this was that the list comprehension would send the data to the driver , like a for loop, and I would get an out of memory problem. Am I mistaken?

Comment: it won’t send to driver. Workers are still the place where UDF are running. It’s not as efficient as built-in Spark functions, but still had parallelism on it.